# Laravel 9 + Facebook SDK (Undefined array key 1)

Tags: php, laravel, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm following this Facebook installation and integration guide, but it's not working.

Guide link: https://quantizd.com/facebook-php-sdk-with-laravel/

I get a **"Undefined array key 1"** error after following all the steps and trying to post to my Facebook Page.

```
$response = $this->api->get('/me/accounts', Auth::user()->token);
```

I can't find documentation anywhere on what could be the reason for the error.

I appreciate if someone can help me. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

The sdk is no longer maintained.
Check this page: [enter link description here](https://github.com/facebookarchive/php-graph-sdk/issues/1246)  NouvelleTechno's solution works for me.